# .NET Write Event Handler to Catch Local Exception

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, exception

I am writing a logger for a legacy codebase written in VB.NET which contains a lot of events and functions which have the form:

```
Try
    'Do some stuff here'
Catch ex As Exception
    'Handle the exception here'
EndTry
```

Where the `Try` statement is the first line of the method and the `EndTry` is the last line of the method. Because the code hasn't been maintained over the years, no one is sure if the try-catches are actually necessary. Now, I have written a singleton class that hooks into a logging framework and I can call it like so:

```
With New MyLogger().Logger
    Try
        'Do some stuff here'
    Catch ex As Exception
        .Log("Some message", ex)
    EndTry
EndWith
```

where `MyLogger` is written in .NET 4.0. What I'd like to do here, is remove the inner try-catch and replace it with some event handler in `MyLogger`. I already have `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` wired up but my understanding is that the event will only raise with exceptions that pass all the way through the application without being caught. Is there an event I can handle that will only catch exceptions that make it to the given scope where the object is newed up at? Maybe it would look something like this:

```
public MyLogger()
{
    Something.CurrentScope.UnhandledException += MyHandler;
}

private MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    // log the exception here
}
```

with the following VB.NET code:

```
With New MyLogger().Logger
    'Do some stuff here'
EndWith
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible answer based on updated question

It seems you are looking for a scope-local handler, and I'm pretty positive that there is no such thing as such.

However, you presented:

> ```
> With New MyLogger().Logger
>     Try
>         'Do some stuff here'
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         .Log("Some message", ex)
>     EndTry
> EndWith
> ```

which should, with appropriate initialization, simplify to something along the lines of:

> ```
> With New MyLogger().Logger
>     'Do some stuff here'
> EndWith
> ```

I think that a [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) wrapper could help you here:

Essentially, instead of doing `With Logger ... EndWith` you're gonna do:

```
MyLogger().DoWithCatch(
  Sub()
    ' Do some stuff here
  End Sub
)
```

where `DoWithCatch` would be implemented like

```
Sub DoWithCatch(ByVal lambda As Sub())
  Try
    lambda()
  Catch ex As Exception
    Log("Some message", ex)
  EndTry
End Sub
```

I think you get the idea.

This way, you only write the catch block once.

### What I first said

Possibly, what you are looking for is: [`AppDomain.FirstChanceException Event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.firstchanceexceptioneventargs?view=netframework-4.7.1)

> Provides data for the notification event that is raised when a managed exception first occurs, before the common language runtime begins searching for event handlers.

---

Another global way to be "notified" of all exceptions is to use [Vectored Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/vectored-exception-handling). But that seems to be unmanaged only.

Ref: [Is it possible to do Vectored Strctured exception handling in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660807/is-it-possible-to-do-vectored-strctured-exception-handling-in-c)

Comment: I'd say you've gotten about 85% of it. I do, however, want to be able to catch the exception

Comment: @Woody1193 - I think you need to clarify the question. What's the "inner try-catch" you allude to? Maybe add a small before/after code snippet. At the moment I'm unclear as to what you want removed.